# Fragment setRetainInstance(true) not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that contains a number of Fragments that are swapped based on the selected item in a Navigation Drawer. I am trying to retain the current fragment across an orientation change by calling `setRetainInstance(true)` on the Fragment and then checking if that fragment exists in `onCreate(...)`. However, the Fragment is always null when I try to get it on `onCreate(...)`. I've been banging my head against my desk for hours over this. Can anyone spot a problem?

**Relevant parts of activity**

```
public class StartActivity {

    private static final String MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG = "mainFragment";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        ...

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            if(f == null) {
                // FRAGMENT IS ALWAYS NULL
                switchToModeForPosition(...);
            } else {
                setupActionBarForPosition(...);
            }
        } else {
            // Default to events view
            switchToModeForPosition(0);
        }
    }

    private void switchToModeForPosition(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position) {
            default:
            case 0: //events
                fragment = new EventsByWeekFragment();
                setupActionBarForEvents();
                break;
            case 1: //teams
                fragment = new AllTeamsListFragment();
                setupActionBarForTeams();
                break;
            case 2: //insights
                fragment = new InsightsFragment();
                setupActionBarForInsights();
                break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                return;
        }
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setRetainInstance(true)`it in each `Fragment` class.

```
public void onCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }
```

Or

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have posted that code too. I do that already, in addition to when I'm constructing the fragment in my activity.